Adjust container height based on content within iframe
I'm trying to figure out how to dinamically adjust iframe height based on content. I don't want to see a scrolling behaviour o the iframe on mobile, it's not very UX friendly.
I've tried to set 100% as height, but nothing changed.
Here's the page so you can see what I'm talking about
https://flypont.com/a320-basic-2
(it's the section where you can click "Scegli giorno e ora" or "data aperta". The below content is an iframe. This is the code:
<iframe id="calendario" src="https://app.acuityscheduling.com/catalog.php?owner=31548557&amp;category=A320+Basic" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0"></iframe>

How can i do the customisation?
I tried this but with no result.
<script>
   var iframe = document.getElementById("calendario");
   iframe.width = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
   iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
</script>


"I tried this but with no result." - you do not get JavaScript access to the content of an iframe, that was loaded from a different origin - the Same Origin Policy prevents that. The only way here to adapt the iframe size to whatever height the content inside it actually requires, was if the provider of the iframe content offered active support for that. They would have to implement a script that measures the iframe's own content's height, and then communicate that info to your page via postMessage.

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
    if (iframes && iframes.length) {
        iframes.forEach(iframe => {
            iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
                const content = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument);
                if (content && content.document) {
                    this.height = '';
                    this.height = content.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
                }
            });
        });
    }
});

But, it doesn't support cross-domain.
Maybe you can use this package. The cross-domain iframe sizing issue is solved here:
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer
